# Radio buttons with as-is/update/delete functionality

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, updating

So I have created a table that has 3 radio buttons. I am having trouble understanding how to get each radio button to perform their named task [function]. Here is a picture of my table:

Can someone explain or give me an example as to how to give functionality to these radio buttons. So that when text is edited and say "update" is selected and the submit button is clicked it would update the database.

Here is my code for this section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

//Test Connection
if (!$connection)
{
die ("Could not connct to the database: <br />". mysql_error());
}
//select db
mysql_select_db('Assets');


$sql1= "SELECT gid, gstmnt  FROM Goals";
$records1 = mysql_query($sql1);

//Adding functions to submit

//$gstmnt_up = $_POST['gstmnt'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>List of GOALS/List of SERVICES</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width='800' border='3' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>
<tr>
    <h1>List of Goals</h1>
    <th>GID</th>
    <th width= '200'>Goal Statement</th>
    <!--Sumbit column-->
    <th  width= '85'>
        <form id="EditGoalForm" action="EditGoals.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </th>

</tr>

<!--This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.</p>-->


<?php
while ($gtable = mysql_fetch_assoc($records1)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$gtable['gid']."</td>";

    echo "<td><div id=textarea contenteditable>".$gtable['gstmnt']."</div></td>";

    echo "<td>
              <input type='radio' name=".$gtable['gid']."                                    value='asis' checked> AS-IS </br>
              <input type='radio' name=".$gtable['gid']." id='radio_update".$gtable['gid']." value='update' > Update     </br>
              <input type='radio' name=".$gtable['gid']."                                    value='delete' > Delete
          </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "<td> </td>";

    echo "<td> 
              <input type= 'text name='addGoal' placeholder='ADD NEW GOAL HERE' size='100'>
          </td>";

    echo "<td> 
              <input type='checkbox' name='add' value='checked'> Add Goal
          </td>";
    ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: Google "update mysql".

Comment: I know how to udpate mysql with such syntax as: "UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value "

Now connecting the radio buttons to this syntax is my issue.

Comment: There you go :-) Now show us what you tried that may have failed. If not, then keep on searching. There are tons of examples out there, you don't need us.